# Is it the "Stack Exchange Network" or the "Stack Overflow Network"?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-button

When I first visit a Stack Exchange site using a different computer, browser, Incognito mode, etc. the cookie footer appears at the bottom (as it should).

The message, however, says

> Your use of **Stack Overflow's** Products and Services, including the **Stack Overflow Network**, is subject to these policies and terms.

[image: stack overflow network]
<sub>*(Emphasis added)*</sub>

However, clicking the StackExchange button at the top of any site says

> #### Stack Exchange Network
>
> **Stack Exchange network** consists of 174 Q&A communities...

[image: stack exchange(tm) network]

Is "Stack Overflow Network" or "Stack Exchange Network" correct?

Comment: Although it's a different question, you'll find your answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270037/323179)

Comment: I already mentioned this here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310443/how-do-i-opt-out-of-cookies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's definitely the "Stack Exchange Network".

What can sometimes get confusing is that the brand name for the entity that runs said network is "Stack Overflow", not "Stack Exchange". So, sometimes you *will* see someone say "Stack Overflow" when talking about the company and not the literal site `stackoverflow.com`.

It's possible that's where this error came from. Someone started the copy with "Stack Overflow" and then was in the process of changing it to "Stack Exchange Network" to be less ambiguous, but only added "Network" without changing "Overflow" to "Exchange".

There's also the possibility that for GDPR reasons (which is why this banner exists), this is by design... so let me get some more info and get back.

We've fixed the text so that it's more general and less confusing:

[image: Updated Terms of Service banner text "By using our site you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and Terms of Service"]

Comment: Please also respond to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310443/how-do-i-opt-out-of-cookies, as I had mentioned this bug there as an aside.

Comment: And some artfully rotten produce for pelting I suppose.

Comment: Worth noting that the company was called Stack Exchange [until Sept 2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/). Personally I think Stack Exchange would still be a better name, but we all know that sometimes you have to make sales driven choices. Stack Overflow still has a bigger profile.

Comment: @curiousdannii The company has, and always has been, legally known as "Stack Exchange, Inc." The blog post you refer to is just a rebranding. They didn't change the *legal* name. (In fact, it *can't* be called "Stack Overflow", as they ran into problems when originally registering that and ended up calling it "Stack Overflow Internet Services").