# Terms of Service begins with "Stack Overflow Network" instead of "Stack Exchange Network"

Tags: bug, legal, terms-of-service, trademark

According to the [Trademark Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance), the name of the network of Q&A sites is the "Stack Exchange Network". Yet the [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal) begins with the word "Stack Overflow Network":

> [image: "Stack Overflow Network"]

There was a [prior bug filed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315154/is-it-the-stack-exchange-network-or-the-stack-overflow-network) where the cookie warning mentioned "Stack Overflow Network", and the official response to that was that the official name was indeed "Stack Exchange Network" and that it said something different was a bug.

Can the Terms of Service please be corrected?