# Can we process the [faq-proposed] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-faq

This Meta site has a tag called [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) for people to propose questions being added to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931). The tag currently has 130 questions, many of which are now *years* old. I believe that lots of these questions are [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)-worthy, but it would require a great deal of effort from the moderators to decide which of the proposals to tag.

Are there any plans going forward to process the questions in the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag?

Comment: Mind listing the specific ones you find [tag:faq]-worthy?

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog There's plenty of quality consensus but in the end my personal opinion on the questions doesn't matter greatly - this is more just asking if anything's going to be done with the backlog of questions.

Comment: Still, though, to bolster your case (since this is being negatively received at the moment), it would be nice to cite some specific cases that, in your opinion, are worthy of being promoted.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog [Just](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319353/) [to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316904/) [name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314553/) [a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310443/) [few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295936/). Obviously they'd still need a bit of tailoring to be perfect for the FAQ.

Comment: Just a thought -- maybe it would help if you started polishing them, bit by bit.